# FireLog: proper installation

Tags: macos, kernel, iokit

I have installed the firewiresdk26 on my dev mac...
and in the Tools/ directory is FireLog.
I have run the FireLog 2.0.0.pkg installer on my dev mac,
but the payload it deploys is installed in my /System/Library
tree, as opposed to my /Developer/SDKs tree. so when I try to include the header iokit/firewire/FireLog.h it does not get found.

am I missing something? or doing something wrong?

or is this an error in the installer (either FW26 or FireLog installers?)
I realize that the FireLog installer is intended to be run on the machine to be debugged remotely and thus it makes sense that the framework is placed in the /System/Library path,
however none of the installers gets it into my developer path... I guess I just have to move it over there by hand, but before I do that I wanted to see if I'm just overlooking something silly and need to read the docs with more concentration or something...

anyone run into this before?   [thx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it turns out, the answer is quite simple...
As of 10.5 Leopard, FireLog facilities are built into the OS and the FireLog app / framework are no longer needed at all!

refer to FireWireKPrintf Readme.txt

and

man fwkpfv

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually install the header files into:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/IOKit/firewire/IOFireLog.h
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/IOKit/firewire/IOFireLog.h
```

You could accomplish the same thing by simply adding the FireLog declaration to a header file in your project:

```
void FireLog( const char *format, ... );
```

FireLog is much higher performance than FireWireKprintf, so it may be advantageous to use, particularly in cases where logging rapid activity with less performance degradation is desirable.